# Implicit event object passing in error event listener

Tags: javascript, promise, addeventlistener

Take this Javascript Promise as an example:

```
const loadImage = (src) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener(`load`,()=>resolve(img));
    img.addEventListener(`error`,(event)=>reject(event));
    img.src=src;
});
```

I've been told that

```
img.addEventListener('error', event => reject(event))
```

is the same as

```
img.addEventListener('error', reject)
```

is it? Can you explain how does the implicit `event` object passage mechanism works in Javascript?

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback

Answer (score 1):

When you're declaring a callback directly:

```
img.addEventListener('error', event => reject(event));
```

You're creating an anonymous function that takes one argument which is passed to the next function. We can name this anonymous function, like:

```
const myFunc = argument => reject(argument);
img.addEventListener('error', myFunc);
```

So this is just a proxy for the input arguments that are passed further. So it may be concidered as an extra layer that can be reduced, so we'll just use `reject` instead of `myFunc` and get the same result.

```
img.addEventListener('error', reject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are doing the same thing,

```
img.addEventListener('error', event => reject(event))
```

is passing `addEventListener` an anonymous function that receives a parameter called `event` and passes it to `reject`, while

```
img.addEventListener('error', reject)
```

is passing it a function too, just not anonymous, but by reference. `reject` also receives a parameter, so it's passed the same way as with the anonymous function